# Removing the word "Curriculum Vitae" from the hyndman template of vitae package in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

### Goal

Create an Rmarkdown file with hyndman template from [vitae](https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae) package for writing a cover letter.

### Problem

I can use the hyndman template to generate a pdf, but it contains the words "Curriculum Vitae" in the headers as shown below.

[image]

### Question and what I tried

I want to remove "Curriculum Vitae" from headers so that I can use this template for cover letter too. I have checked the .sty files, rmarkdown file, and vitae package files, but I can't locate "Curriculum Vitae". How can I remove these words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should search the Github page for that text.  When I did, I found it occurring lots of times in comments, and once here:

https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae/blob/40a47e2fe9c1573cc980b6be812217207283ff7e/inst/rmarkdown/templates/hyndman/resources/hyndmantemplate.tex#L212

I stopped looking then, so the source of the line you don't like might be elsewhere, but if it's here, it looks as though all you need to do is to put

```
docname:  Letter
```

in the YAML header (or something similar, perhaps even a blank).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing the `docname` did the trick.